# python flask upload an image and display it in the same html page

Tags: python, flask

I would like to upload an image and then display that image directly in the same page, under the "Choose file" button, same as shown in the attached picture:

[image: example]

I found a solution for Java, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138579/how-to-upload-an-image-and-display-it-in-the-same-page-using-html-javascript)

For Flask, I had a look at other threads, for example:

[python flask display image on a html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785507/python-flask-display-image-on-a-html-page)

[How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

However, they are not exactly what I am looking for. I also found a similar question, which has not been answered yet:

[Upload an Image and Display it back as a response using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825157/upload-an-image-and-display-it-back-as-a-response-using-flask)

My main idea is having a `form` with `input` `type` of `file`:

```
<form method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" name="input_img">
</form>
```

After uploading the image, it will be displayed directly under the upload button. Does anybody know how to do it with Python Flask?

Comment: If you want to preview the image before uploading [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded). If you want to upload to server first [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926465/upload-image-in-flask)

Comment: @kudeh I would like to upload it to the server, but the second link you sent is not what I am looking for. In that thread, the image is uploaded to another the html page ``('/register')``, not in the same html page, where the upload button is located